# CSS file that contains top navigation bar font style SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, css

How do I edit the CSS of the top navigation bar in SharePoint Online? Specifically, I would like to edit the font size.

Answer (score 1):

Where?

- Classic Experiences, with your own CSS overruling ms- selectors (CSS Specificity)
- Modern Experiences, not possible (or not yet as Microsoft keeps saying since May 2016)

Comment: Thanks, Danny. I am using the classic experience. Which anchors/classes would I be altering specifically?

Comment: Open up F12 console and check yourself. I don't know all that stuff by heart.. its hundreds of selectors and depends on what you want to do..